# Error expected near on Splash Lua Script

Tags: python, lua, syntax-error, scrapy-splash, splash-js-render

I need to run this simple Lua script on Splash:

```
    script = """
    function main(splash)
        local url = splash.args.url
        assert(splash:go(url))
        assert(splash:wait(1))

        -- go back 1 month in time and wait a little (1 second)
        assert(splash:runjs("$('a[data-ci-test-id=\"checkOutButton\"]').click()"))
        assert(splash:wait(1))

        -- return result as a JSON object
        return {
            html = splash:html(),
            -- we don't need screenshot or network activity
            --png = splash:png(),
            --har = splash:har(),
        }
    end
    """
```

But I got this error:

```
{u'info': {u'source': u'[string "..."]', u'message': u'[string "..."]:8: \')\' expected near \'checkOutButton\'', u'line_number': 8, u'type': u'LUA_INIT_ERROR', u'error': u"')' expected near 'checkOutButton'"}, u'type': u'ScriptError', u'description': u'Error happened while executing Lua script', u'error': 400}
```

How should I write the CSS selector string for this script to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer based on another answer even though the error string is not the same. 
[Use scrapy + splash return html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41614472/use-scrapy-splash-return-html)

It turns out, the page I scrape had no JQuery, so I have to load the JQuery package first.

```
    script = """
    function main(splash)
        # add this vvv
        assert(splash:autoload("https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"))
        local url = splash.args.url
        assert(splash:go(url))
        assert(splash:wait(1))

        -- go back 1 month in time and wait a little (1 second)
        assert(splash:runjs("$('div.minicart_summery > a.btn_checkout').click()"))
        assert(splash:wait(1))

        -- return result as a JSON object
        return {
            html = splash:html(),
            -- we don't need screenshot or network activity
            --png = splash:png(),
            --har = splash:har(),
        }
    end
    """
```